# Как избавиться от "Показать ещё фотографии" при парсинге картинок в альбомах в вк?

Tags: python, парсер

Я написал код, который скачивает картинки с альбомов в вк.
Возникла проблема с тем, что при получении html сайта, отображаются только 36 картинок, а затем идёт ссылка  "Показать ещё картинки" с href = "/ссылка на альбом?offset=36#photos".
[image: В изображении конец списка фотографий]
Я пытался поменять оффсет, ничего не поменялось (изначальная ссылка была без него).
Вопрос в том, можно ли как-то убрать это ограничение?
Вот код парсера:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def download_images(site, id):
    response = requests.get(site)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    img_tags = soup.find_all('img')

    urls = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

    for url in urls:
        with open(folder + "/" + str(id) + '.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            try:
                response = requests.get(url)
                f.write(response.content)
                print(f'Success: {url}')
                break
            except:
                pass

def get_sites(site):
    response = requests.get(site)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    sites = [i['href'] for i in soup.find_all('a') if i['href'].find('photo') != -1]
    return sites

site = input("URL: ")
folder = input("Folder: ")

sites = get_sites(site)

for id, a in enumerate(sites):
    print(a, id)
    download_images('https://vk.com/' + a, id)
```